# How to detect and highlight rectangle on mouse hover

Tags: c#, .net, window, gdi+

I have created a windows application control in C#.net to show some objects in graphical mode.
To do so I created a rectangles depend on number of items I got in list and plot it over control by using Control OnPaint event.

Now I want to highlight that rectangle if mouse hovering on it.

Please check attached image for more clarity & suggest me how can I achieve it .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the classical DrawCli example? It shows how a basic application should manage objects and tools.

In short you should re-enumerate your list inside `MouseMove` event, get the item's rect and set its `IsFocused` property to true if mouse pointer is inside that rect. Then redraw if something changed. You may even do that inside your `OnPaint` (check current mouse position) but then you have to always redraw everything inside `MouseMove` (and it's a very bad idea).

Kind of pseudo-code to explain what I mean:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   foreach (GraphicalObject obj in Objects)
   {
      if (!obj.IsVisible)
            continue;

      Rectangle rect = obj.GetBounds(e.Graphics);
      if (!rect.Intersects(e.ClipRectangle))
         continue;

      obj.Draw(e.Graphics);
   }
}
```

`GraphicalObject` is the base type for all objects you can put on the screen. `Objects` is a property that contains the collection of them (`GraphicalObjectCollection`, for example). Now you code may be like this (note that this is far aways from true code, it's just an example of a general technique):

```
protected override OnMouseMove(MouseMoveEventArgs e)
{
   bool needToRedraw = false;

   using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
   {
      foreach (GraphicalObject obj in Objects)
      {
         if (!obj.IsVisible)
               continue;

         Rectangle rect = obj.GetBounds(e.Graphics);
         if (rect.Contains(e.Location))
         {
            if (!obj.IsFocused)
            {
               obj.IsFocused = true;
               needToRedraw = true;
            }
         }
         else
         {
            if (obj.IsFocused)
            {
               obj.IsFocused = false;
               needToRedraw = true;
            }
         }

         obj.Draw(e.Graphics);
      }
   }

   if (needToRedraw)
      Invalidate();
}
```