# How do I keep previously painted objects from disappearing when a new one is creating in a Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms

My problem is that within my Windows Form Application, I want to draw an Ellipse everytime the mouse is clicked within a specific picture box, and I want the previously drawn ellipses to remain present in the picture box.

In its current state, once the mouse is clicked, the previously drawn ellipse will be replaced with the new one drawn at the cursor's new location.

Ball.Paint draws an ellipse.

Here is the relevant code to the problem:

```
    private Ball b;

    private void pbField_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (b != null)
            b.Paint(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void pbField_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {           
        int width = 10;
        b = new Ball(new Point(e.X - width / 2, e.Y - width / 2), width);
        Refresh();
    }
```

If there is any more needed code or information I am able to provide it.

Comment: It's the Refresh() that clears the old ones... But leaving it out is not the solution.

Comment: Starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12624450/1207195

Comment: The problem is that each ball object falls out of scope and no longer exists. When you call a Refresh(), the view is redrawn and the non-existent balls are removed. Try adding them to a collection of some sort like a List or array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some sort of data structure to store prior ellipses.  One possible solution is below:

```
private List<Ball> balls = new List<Ball>(); // Style Note:  Don't do this, initialize in the constructor.  I know it's legal, but it can cause issues with some code analysis tools.

private void pbField_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Ball b in balls)
    {
        if (b != null)
        {
            b.Paint(e.Graphics);
        }
    }
}

private void pbField_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{           
    int width = 10;
    b = new Ball(new Point(e.X - width / 2, e.Y - width / 2), width);
    balls.Add(b);
    Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was attempting to use a list before but forgot about foreach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one ball to be painted, you need to keep track of a list of balls, rather than just `b`.  Every time the control is refreshed, it is expected to redraw *all* its contents.  That means that in `pbField_Paint`, you need to be ready to draw as many balls as have been added to the scene.